# Convert values from nested dictionary to an array of dictionaries

Tags: javascript

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
{key1: {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, key2: {"A": 2, "B": 2, "C": 2}, ...}
```

I would like to place the values of from this dictionary into an array, like this:

```
[{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, {"A": 2, "B": 2, "C": 2}, ...]
```

How can I convert a nested dictionary into an array of dictionaries where each element in the array is the values from the original nested dictionary?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the array?

Comment: order is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push every entry in the object into an array.

```
var obj = {key1: {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, key2: {"A": 2, "B": 2, "C": 2}};
var arr = [];
for(var i in obj) {
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
  arr.push(obj[i]);
}
```

`arr` will then look like this:

```
[{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3},{"A":2,"B":2,"C":2}]
```

You can see this [in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d2WW/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var stuff = {key1: {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, key2: {"A": 2, "B": 2, "C": 2} }
var result = []
for ( var key in stuff ) {
  result.push( stuff[key] )
}
```